# Is stripe or paystack incompatible with react18

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, react-18, paystack

l'm trying to build an Amazon clone, is paystack or stripe incompatible with react 18, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: If these vendor products have a dependency on React (do they?) then surely the vendor's documentation specifies the required version.  This sounds like something to ask the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

[@stripe/react-stripe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js) doesn't currently support React 18, but plan to ([#273](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/273)) as per their official [github](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#requirements)